# Should I use __new__ to prevent instantiation?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm building my own lightweight orm. I'd like to keep instantiated objects in a class variable (perhaps a dictionary). When I request an object (through a class method) like get(id), I'd like to return the object from the instantiated list, or create one if it does not exist.

Is there a way to prevent the instantiation of an object (if its id already exists in the cls list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two straightforward ways of doing it - and many other ways,as well. One of them, as you suggest, is to write the `__new__` method for your objects, which could return an already existing object or create a new instance.

Another way is to use a factory function for your objects - and call this factory function instead of the class - more or less like this:

```
class _MyClass(object):
    pass

def MyClass(*args, **kw):
    if not "my_class_object" in all_objects:
         all_objects["my_class_object"] = _MyClass(*args, **kw)
    return all_objects["my_class_object"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just perform explicit check, it is the cleanest method, I believe:

```py
class OrmContainer(object):
    objects = {}

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        if id not in cls.objects:
            cls.objects[id] = SomeOtherClass(id)
        return cls.objects[id]
```